# Why multiple line shell code doesn't fail the bulid in codebuild project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am using `codebuild` for CI and I implement some scripts in build spec file. A piece of the code is a multiple line `if` command, like:

```sh
 - |
        if [ [ -v $DB_TABLE_NAME  ] && [ $IS_PRIMARY_REGION != 'true' ] ]; then
          yarn test 
        elif [ [ $IS_PRIMARY_REGION == 'false' ] ]; then
          yarn test $PRIMARY_REGION
        fi
```

the issue is if `yarn test` inside `if` fail, the codebuild project doesn't fail. It finished as success. How can I make the multiple line statement fail the build?

Comment: And if ` yarn test` outside of `if`, then it works correctly?

Comment: @joey-yi-zhao I'm experiencing this issue as well; did you come up with a solution.  (Not specific to yarn, it's a general issue).  Marcin: Yes, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Running a multi-line Codebuild command is like running a bash script. If you want the command to fail if any line (sub-command) returns a non-zero exit status, you'll have to add a `set -e` at the beginning of your command. It instructs the "script" to terminate with error as soon as any command it executes fails.

##### Example

This will display "before" AND "after".

```yaml
commands:
  - |
    echo "before"
    false
    echo "after"
```

This will only display "before", then the execution will fail.

```yaml
commands:
  - |
    set -e
    echo "before"
    false
    echo "after"
```